# index: adding (e) after page number

Tags: indexing

I am completing the index of a book. After the page number, when the page refers to an exercice, I would like to add an (e). For instance:

rotation ..... 117, 510(e), 1124

Is this easily possible? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define the command `\newcommand{\ex}[1]{#1(e)}` in the preamble of your document. Then, when you use the `\index` command within an exercise, use it as follows: `\index{example|ex}`.

Comment: Many thanks José! It works beautifully well, and it is also very simple. I was afraid it would interfere with the subcategories of the index or entries afrer @, but it does not. It is perfect!